# Should I add an expired certificate to my references?

Tags: job-search, new-job, job-change, career-switch

In September 2010 I acquired the [Cisco Certified Network Associate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCNA) (CCNA) certificate.

This certificate are only valid for three years. One is expected to do a recertification.

Because I haven't done this mine is expired in 2013.

But nevertheless: I had to learn all that stuff about computer networks once, I have passed the exam. And most of the exam's content, which isn't Cisco specific, is still the same. Perhaps even much of the Cisco-near content is still unchanged.

Therefore my question:

Should I add the certification document to my references when sending a job application?

I mean: As long as I don't call myself "CCNA" (on business cards) I don't do any fraud.

I just want to show that I went once through the learning process which is without doubt true.

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't put "Cisco Certified Network Associate 2010-2013".

Comment: Yet another expired Cisco certificate. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, don't draw undue attention to it, but put CCNA somewhere. If necessary you can always recertify. But CCNA is entry level, so the people who would actually know about CCNA wouldn't be very fussed over it expiring.

It's an added expense that few people would go to to recertify for little return. The important bit is that you passed the kindergarten exam and now have 6 years experience.

Comment: Exactly - it's not like the knowledge needed for certification evaporates on expiry, especially if there is more recent experience to point to

Comment: +1, as in my workspace its a strong requierement to have the ccna, expired or not. they just want you to know the stuff.

Comment: Could you discretely add the date you received it? People who know about it should know it is only valid for 3 years, and you aren't then providing false information.